# JQuery validation Element error/valid css not showing

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css, validation, highlight

I am using Jquery Validation on a `user control` as such:

```
 $("#form1").validate({
                 rules: {
                            <%=textb.UniqueID  %>: 
                            { 
                                required: true 
                            },
                        },
                messages: {
                            <%=textb.UniqueID  %>:
                                {
                                    required: "Please Enter value",
                                },
                        },
                highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
                           //$(element).css({ backgroundColor: '#0f0' });
                           $(element).addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
                        },
                unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
                            //$(element).css({ backgroundColor: '#fff' });
                           $(element).removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass);
                          }
            });
```

This is the CSS I am using:

```
.error input {
    color: #b92d23;
}
.error {
      background: #000;
}
```

Now I can see the `error` and `valid` classes added to the input/textbox. but the CSS won't take effect to change the background colour.

If I do `$(element).css({ backgroundColor: '#fff' });` it changes the colour but want to do it from CSS file(I can see my other CSS class but not error).

In firebug it looks like this :

```
<input type="text" class="UC_longtextfield error" id="mypage_txbLoanAmount" name="mypage$txbLoanAmount">
<label for="mypage_txbLoanAmount" generated="true" class="error">Please Enter value</label>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your css is wrong

```
input.error {
    color: #b92d23;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

have you checked the CSS file path? Are you able to see css file gets added to the your page?

If css file is added to ur page properly then you need to check whether error/valid classes are being added to the input element properly or not?

If css get loaded properly and classes gets added to the input element then below styles should reflect on that particular element:

```
input.error {
color: #b92d23;
}
```